# Commutation relation between pairs of conjugated variables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, canonical-conjugation

Suppose I have four operators $\hat{q}_1$, $\hat{p}_1$, $\hat{q}_2$ and $\hat{p}_2$ such that

1. $[\hat{q}_1, \hat{p}_1] = [\hat{q}_2, \hat{p}_2] = i$
2. $[\hat{q}_1, \hat{q}_2] = [\hat{p}_1, \hat{p}_2] = [\hat{q}_1, \hat{p}_2] = 0$

That is, these operators are similar to a pair of distinct canonical conjugated variables except that I don't know the value of the *missing* commutator $[\hat{q}_2, \hat{p}_1]$.

Do you know if I can derive its value from the above commutation relations? Intuitively, it seems like it should be zero, but I don't see a way to prove it.

If it can help, the operator are generally defined as functions of the position $\hat{q}$ and momentum $\hat{p}$ operators. That is,
$\hat{q}_1 = f(\hat{q})$ and $\hat{p}_1 = \frac{1}{f'(\hat{q})} \hat{p}$.
Similarly, $\hat{p}_2 = g(\hat{p})$ and $\hat{q}_2 = \frac{1}{g'(\hat{p})} \hat{q}$. We pick $f$ and $g$ to satisfy the above commutation relations. An example would be $f(\hat{q}) = \frac{1}{a} \sin(a \hat{q})$
and $g(\hat{p}) = \frac{1}{b} \sin(b \hat{p})$ with $a b = 2 \pi m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample: Take $\hat{q}_1=q_1$ (multiplication with $q_1$), $\hat{q}_2=q_2$ (multiplication with $q_2$), $\hat{p}_1=-i\partial/\partial q_1-i\alpha \partial/\partial q_2$ with an arbitrary constant $\alpha \ne 0$ and $\hat{p}_2= -i \partial/\partial q_2$. The commutation relations $[\hat{q}_1,\hat{p}_1]=[\hat{q}_2,\hat{p}_2]=i$ and $[\hat{q}_1,\hat{q}_2]=[\hat{p}_1,\hat{p}_2]=[\hat{q}_1,\hat{p}_2]=0$ are fulfilled, but $[\hat{q}_2,\hat{p}_1]=i\alpha \ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that in general you can find a counter example. But, it is not obvious for me to find a counter example when restricting to the particular construction I gave. Do you happen to have a counter example for this case too?